# Error writing on apache2

Tags: 12.04, apache2, owncloud-server

I've problem when I want to write on apache2

```
$ nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default  
Error writing /etc/apache2/sites-available/default: Permission denied
```

I've installed

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite ; sudo a2enmod headers
```

but the result still `error: permission denied`.

anyone have trouble same with me, can share to fix it.

thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sudo command`, for example `sudo nano`, when you want to change something in `/etc` directory, because it is system directory. This is default security measure in Ubuntu.

Use

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

or

```
sudoedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

---

Also, you can check permissions of the file using `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
-r-------- 1 root root 1411 march 11 11:41 /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

In the above example file permissions are set not allowing for writing. Let's fix it:

```
$ sudo chmod u+w /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
$ ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
-rw------- 1 root root 1411 march 11 11:41 /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

However, it's just a dirty example of using `chmod`, because `root` does not need the `w` flag to be able to write to a file, he doesn't even need to be an owner.

Comment: sudo command /etc/apache2/sites-available/default,

Comment: What command do you use?

Comment: i using this command , sudo command /etc/apache2/sites-available/default,

Comment: No, the _command_ is just template. Use, for example, `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

Comment: ohh, i using nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Comment: Look into the updated answer.

Comment: @user254556: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: @Dan, added the full command.